# opencv 3.0 contrib seeds.py

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use `opencv_contrib` modules but after built the latest `opencv (3.0)` and `opencv_contrib` with success, when I run the sample in `opencv_contrib` folder in python2 subfolder I get this:

```
opencv_contrib/samples/python2$ python seeds.py

This sample demonstrates SEEDS Superpixels segmentation
Use [space] to toggle output mode

Usage:
  seeds.py [<video source>]


init done 
opengl support available 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seeds.py", line 54, in <module>
    seeds = cv2.ximgproc.createSuperpixelSEEDS(width, height, channels,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ximgproc'
```

What I missed?

Comment: you can shortcut the test with: `import cv2; help(cv2.ximgproc);` if you still get the same error, you will have to go back to cmake / make / install

Comment: thanks! the error was the version of opencv and opencv_contrib. Must have the same version so i download opencv 3.0 and opencv_contrib 3.0 without clone the github. Then i rebuild and all is fine.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It says you need to provide a video source after `seeds.py`, as mentioned in this message:

```
Usage:
  seeds.py [<video source>]
           ^
```

Comment: correct, but not the actual cause. (an import statement in python will get evaluated before parsing cmdline args)